# JaxB inheritance marshalling abstract classes

Tags: java, xml, inheritance, jaxb, moxy

I've been searching for the best way to perform the following action using JaxB but I cannot find a way that works. I followed the tutorial [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/01/jaxb-and-inhertiance-using-xmladapter.html) to allow for marshaling and unmarshaling of subclasses.

It achieves all that I am looking for, except that in order for the subclasses to be properly marshaled and unmarshaled, they must be wrapped in a class with a specific `@XmlRootElement`. This doesn't allow you to represent the classes themselves as Xml on their own.

I want to have a classes like so:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;   

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ContactMethodAdapter.class) 
public abstract class ContactMethod {   

}

public class Address extends ContactMethod {       

    protected String street;      
    protected String city;   

}

public class PhoneNumber extends ContactMethod {       

    protected String number;   

}
```

and I want to be able to perform the following:

Input:

```
<contact-method>
   <street>Broadway</street>
   <city>Seattle</city>
</contact-method>
```

Main:

```
public class Demo {       
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {         
      ContactMethod meth = (ContactMethod ) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

      if(ContactMethod instanceof Address){
         Address addr = (Address) meth;

         addr.getStreet();

         // etc.
      }

      Address marshalAddr = new Address("Broadway", "Seattle");       

      Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();         
      marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);         
      marshaller.marshal((ContactMethod) marshalAddr, System.out);     
   }   
}
```

Output:

```
<contact-method>
   <street>Broadway</street>
   <city>Seattle</city>
</contact-method>
```

does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

Comment: What XML representation are you trying to achieve?  Are you trying to determine the subclass strictly by which elements are present?

Comment: Basically I wanted to marshal either phone number or address into a <contact-method> root and have them be able to unmarshaled to their proper subclass without having to be wrapped into a list as in your example. 

After reading this other question, You said "@XmlJavaTypeAdapter only applies to fields/properties referencing that class, and not when an instance of that class is a root object in your XML tree." 

This makes me think I should make another class AdapterContactMethod much like you have in the XmlAdapter annotate it with XmlRootElement and handle the subclass conversion myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using one class (AdaptedContactMethod) to model the abstract class. Then I handled the marshaling and unmarshalling to the different subclasses on my own rather than through an `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`.

This allows you to put `@XmlRootElement` on your AdaptedContactMethod implementation without having to wrap it in a list.