# JAXB marshalling of user extended a Date object always results in empty XML

Tags: jaxb

I have a a class that has many fields, some of which are dates.  Specifically, they are MyDate objects, where my MyDate class extends java.util.Date.

When I marshal my top-level class, the date fields show up in the resulting XML, but have no contents.  BTW I have verified that the fields in my top-level object are not null, they do reference legitimate MyDate objects.  So I get XML that looks like
`<TopLevelObject>
    <address>1234</address>
    <startDate></startDate>
    <endDate></endDate>
    . . .
</TopLevelObject>`

I tried annotating the MyDate class so that I could marshal a single MyDate object, and I get basically the same results:
`<MyDate></MyDate>`
I have confirmed that the object that I'm marshaling exists and contains a reasonable date.

Is there something about marshaling an object of a derived class that I don't understand?

I've tried turning on Jaxb debugging (by putting -Djaxb.debug=true) on the java command line.  That results in some output, but nothing that I find helpful.

EDIT:  Before Blaise responded, I tried adding
`@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")`
just before the declaration of each MyDate attribute in my model class.  This seemed to cause the marshaling code to crash partway through creating the XML.  The resulting XML just stops in mid-line; there is no indication anywhere of an exception being thrown or a stack trace or anything like that.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `MyDate` which is an extension of `java.util.Date` is being treated by JAXB as a model class instead of a `Date` class.  Therefore it will only marshal public fields and properties, or JAXB annotated fields/properties.  If you want it treated as a `java.util.Date` you can create an `XmlAdapter` for it.

```java
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class MyDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Date, MyDate> {

    @Override
    public MyDate unmarshal(Date date) throws Exception {
        // TODO Add logic to convert Date to MyDate
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public Date marshal(MyDate myDate) throws Exception {
        return myDate;
    }

}
```

To always have this `XmlAdapter` applied to your `MyDate` class you can annotate `MyDate` with the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation:

```java
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MyDateAdapter.class)
public class MyDate extends Date {

}
```

### UPDATE

> What is it that controls whether a class is treated as a model rather
>   than its contents being included in the marshaling?

For the most part classes not in a standard Java SE package will be treated as a domain object.

> Also, when I create that XmlAdapter class, do I just plonk it down
>   next to MyDate.java in my source directory, or do I need to create a
>   reference to it somewhere else?

The `XmlAdapter` is referenced from the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation.

Comment: Thanks, Blaise, I've already gotten other good information from your blog.  What is it that controls whether a class is treated as a model rather than its contents being included in the marshaling?  Also, when I create that XmlAdapter class, do I just plonk it down next to MyDate.java in my source directory, or do I need to create a reference to it somewhere else?

Comment: @Topher - An `XmlAdapter` isn't applied to an object when it is the root object.  Here is how you could apply it manually:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/23091591/383861

Comment: I tried this XmlAdapter suggestion, and it works for getting the dates in my model object marshaled.  Curiously, when I try to marshal just a single MyDate object, that still does not generate any meaningful output, but that isn't a problem for me now.  Also, I didn't have to create any kind of reference to the new MyDateAdapter class other than the annotation in MyDate.